# How to get dynamic months range on axis in d3.js?

Tags: d3.js, gantt-chart

I am working on gantt chart in d3.js , i want to display 18 months on X-Axis which includes Past 6 months and Future 11 months, 18 months in total. By using following code i am getting months on X-Axis according to start date and endDates of tasks (Y-Axis).

```
var timeDomainStart = d3.time.day.offset(new Date(),-0);
var timeDomainEnd = d3.time.day.offset(new Date(),+0);

var initTimeDomain = function() {
     if (timeDomainMode === FIT_TIME_DOMAIN_MODE) {
         tasks.sort(function(a, b) {
         return a.endDate - b.endDate;
         });
    timeDomainEnd = tasks[tasks.length - 1].endDate;

    tasks.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.startDate - b.startDate;
    });
    timeDomainStart = tasks[0].startDate;

}
};

var initAxis = function() {
      x = d3.time.scale().domain([ timeDomainStart, timeDomainEnd ])
         .range([ 0, width ]).clamp(true);
      y = d3.scale.ordinal().domain(taskTypes)
          .rangeRoundBands([ 0, height - margin.top - margin.bottom ], .25);

    xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient("top").tickFormat(d3.time.format(tickFormat))
    .tickSize(0).tickPadding(10);

yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y).orient("left").tickSize(0).tickPadding(5);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Somehow below snippet worked for me..!!

```
 var initTimeDomain = function() {
    if (timeDomainMode === FIT_TIME_DOMAIN_MODE) {

    tasks.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.startDate - b.startDate;
    });
    timeDomainStart = d3.time.day.offset(new Date(),-180);
    console.log(timeDomainStart);


    tasks.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.endDate - b.endDate;
    });

    timeDomainEnd = d3.time.day.offset(new Date(),+330);
    console.log(timeDomainEnd);

}
};
```